# Code::Blocks, process terminated with status 2 unexpected "(" C programming language

Tags: c, syntax-error, codeblocks

I've just installed Code::Blocks. To check if it all worked I created a new project I made a hello world program in C that went like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  printf("hello, world");
}
```

However when I go to compile it I get this error.

```
-------------- Build: src in Code::Blocks wx2.8.x (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall (invalid) -pipe -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fexceptions -Winvalid-pch -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DcbDEBUG -DCB_PRECOMP -DWX_PRECOMP -DwxUSE_UNICODE -DBUILDING_PLUGIN -iquote.objs/include -I.objs/include -I. -I"(invalid)/include" -I"(invalid)/lib/gcc_dll/mswu" -Isdk/wxscintilla/include -Isdk/wxpropgrid/include -Iinclude/tinyxml -Iinclude -Iinclude/scripting/include -Iinclude/scripting/sqplus -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet/mfbt -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet/nsprpub/pr/include -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet/xpcom -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet/xpcom/base -Iinclude/mozilla_chardet/xpcom/glue -c /home/jackphd/trunk/src/include/sdk.h -o .objs/include/sdk.h.gch
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

When the 
    `select source` 
dialogue comes up I select 
`src` 
tick
    `this target contains this target contains the project's main executable` 
and
        `Run host in terminal`

I've tried changing the project file, getting rid of the parenthesis looking up the same program on the web to see if the syntax had changed since the documentation I'm reading had been published but to no avail.

Comment: Probably won't fix your issue, but `main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Thanks. But, why would the documentation say otherwise?

Comment: Are you asking where in the documentation it is said that `int main(void)` is correct?

Comment: @CoolGuy, he is using `g++`, which is C++ compiler. In C++ you use `func()` signature instead of `func(void)`, when function doesn't take parameters. Also, if return type is not specified, it's `int` by default (both in C and C++). It's a bad style though, one should use `int main()` in C++, to specify explicitly that return type is `int`.

Comment: I told Code::Blocks to use GCC which should be multi language. Does Code::Blocks just naturally default to C++ for some reason?

Comment: my advice would be : dont use code:blocks, MinGW, gcc, g++ or any other OSS-toolchain _IF_ you're trying to develop software for windows. This is an ugly truth you wont hear very often, its quite uncomfortable yet true : OSS libraries often have various problems under windows because everyone tries to re-invent the wheel or even hack microsoft-software. If you want to create RELIABLE software for windows you're pretty much forced to use the microsoft compiler and microsoft libraries - if you REALLY want to avoid that simply write in languages like Java, these are somewhat platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I'm not sure that will be work for you.
Setting->Compiler->Toolchain Executable->auto detect
and then OK.